# Add a `div` over a relatively positioned element

Tags: css

[image]

I want the red box at the arrow ending position. [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/IxAtOFA/13/edit)

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="yellow1">y</div>
<div id="yellow2">y</div>
<div id="red"></div>
</div>


body{width:800px;}

#wrapper{position:relative;}

#blue{
float:left;
height:225px;
width:520px;
background:blue;
}

#yellow1,#yellow2{
position:relative;
width:250px;
height:200px;
margin:10px 0 20px 540px;
background:yellow;}

/*Not working*/
#red{
background:red;
position:absolute;
height:200px;
width:520px;
top:200;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is solved now, I placed the `<div id="red"></div>` before the *yellow* `divs`, http://jsbin.com/IxAtOFA/12/edit

Answer (score 2):

top:520 for #red is wrong. You have to write top:230px as top value I think..

Comment: Also, he is missing the unit of measurement there, and anyways, positioning is very bad.. using `540px` -> `margin:10px 0 20px 540px;` is really weird

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a unit of measurement at the end of `top:520;` of your #red rule
It should be like `top:520px;`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `top` and write `margin-top:-195px` to `#red`.

[Demo here.](http://jsbin.com/AjiWaDI/1/edit)

Comment: nope, it should not be based on the height of the yellow boxes

Answer (score 0):

use this code

http://jsbin.com/IxAtOFA/10/edit

```
#blue{
    float:left;
    height:225px;
    width:520px;
    background:blue;
  margin:5px;
}

#yellow1,#yellow2{
position:relative;
width:250px;
height:200px;
background:yellow;
float:right;
    margin:5px;
}

#red{
  background:red;
  height:200px;
  width:520px;
  float:left;
    margin:5px;
}
```